# Is there a way to assign more than one collection to gfs?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Title says pretty much all, is there a way to assign more than one gfs.collection to when the database connects?

For an example:

```
connect.once('open', () => {
    gfs = grid(connect.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('imgfolder1');
});
```

works but,

```
connect.once('open', () => {
    gfs = grid(connect.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('imgfolder1');
    gfs.collection('imgfolder2');
});
```

does not work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the bucket name. Collection names are derived from the bucket name. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-gridfs/, apply to your driver as needed.

Comment: Thanks man!

I should have explained this in the post, I do specify the bucket name in the database itself, but I cant assign more than one bucket to one database (not that I know of) so when I try to create another database with a different bucket name, the whole database stops working.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense. Review your driver documentation for correct terminology to use then state your problem clearly and precisely.

Comment: You do not specify bucket name in database (there is nothing you would specify in a database at all), you cannot assign buckets to databases, you cannot create databases with bucket names (maybe with database names) and your database is unlikely to stop working.